# Google Volley Listeners

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Google's Volley (a part of AOSP) for handling my networking. I'm wondering if I should create new Listeners (success and error) for each request I make, or is it okay to just create one for each and keep reusing them?

For example, I'm creating a new listener for each request right now:

```
GsonRequest<Object> request = 
    new GsonRequest<Object>(Method.POST, 
         path, 
         Object.class, 
         createSuccessListener(), 
         createErrorListener());
```

where the creation methods are defined as (the createSuccessListener() follows the same idea, so I won't post it):

```
private ErrorListener createErrorListener() {
    return new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) { ... }
    }
}
```

So is it better or worse to create one instance of a listener and use it everywhere I make a request:

```
private ErrorListener mErrorListener;
mListener = createErrorListener();
GsonRequest<Object> request = 
    new GsonRequest<Object>(Method.POST,
        ...
        ...
        mSuccessListener,
        mErrorListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference really. Both are interfaces so they inherently are stateless. It is not harmful to resuse them unless your implementation does not expect being reused.

i.e.

**Not handling state correctly**

```
public class UseOnlyOnceListener implements Listener<Object> {

    boolean hasCompletedAlready;

    public UseOnlyOnceListener() {
       this.hasCompletedAlready = false;
    }

    public void onResponse(T response) {
       this.hasCompletedAlready = ! hasCompletedAlready;
    }

    public boolean hasCompleted() {
       return this.hasCompletedAlready;
    }

}
```

**VS**

```
public class ReusableListener implements Listener<Object> {

   private boolean hasCompletedAlready;

   public ReusableListener() {
      hasCompletedAlready = false;
   }

   public void onSuccess(Object response) {
       this.hasCompletedAlready = true;
   }

   public boolean hasCompleted() {
       return this.hasCompletedAlready;
   }
}
```

**VS**

```
public class ReusableResponses implements Listener<Pair<Request, Object>> {

   private Queue<Pair<Pair<Request, Object>> responses;

   public ReusableListener() {
       responses = new LinkedList<Pair<Request, Object>();
   }

   public void onSuccess(Pair<Request, Object> response) {
       responses.enqueue(pair);
   }

   public boolean hasCompleted() {
       return !responses.isEmpty();
   }

   public List<Pair<Request, Object>> getCompletedResponses() {
       return new ArrayList<Pair<Request, Object>>(responses);
   }
}
```

In the first case, even though you are probably saving memory, the outcome of calling `hasCompleted()` is not reliable if used for multiple requests (I know it's a contrived example, but it's just to display the point). The second case, you can be sure at least one request completed. However that might not be reusable either depending on your app, if you actually need to know what response originated from which request. It's up to your implementation.

Reusing instances does save memory, and lowers object creation time, and reduces GC time. However it is not always convenient and can a lot of times make code much more difficult to read and use. Like I said, it's more of a design issue. Nothing about the interface binds an instance to a single request.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by stateless interfaces? Also, isn't it much more taxing on memory to create a new listener for each request?

Comment: @ynnadkrap updated with more details. Hope it helps, but it mostly depends on your implementation. However it is not required that there is a 1:1 relationship between listener and request